# Class variable scope for static vs class methods

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method, class-variables

I discovered a weird behaviour (at least weird for me) on python class variables.

```
class Base(object):
    _var = 0

    @classmethod
    def inc_class(cls):
        cls._var += 1

    @staticmethod
    def inc_static():
        Base._var += 1

class A(Base):
    pass

class B(Base):
    pass

a = A()
b = B()

a.inc_class()
b.inc_class()
a.inc_static()
b.inc_static()

print(a._var)
print(b._var)
print(Base._var)
```

The output is `1 1 2`.

This is surprising me (I was expecting `4 4 4`) and I'm wondering why?

Comment: If you don't tell us what surprised you, it will be very hard to help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

Comment: Sorry but I did not find any answer to my question on the proposed duplicate thread

Comment: The point of a duplicate is that the same answers will be given. Asking a duplicate question is not the best way to get the answer to a question that's already been asked; bounties are.

Comment: The point of my question is about the class variable, not the class & static methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When decorated with `@classmethod` the first argument `cls` to `inc_class(cls)` is, well, the class. `<class '__main__.A'>` and `<class '__main__.B'>` respectively for `A` and `B`. So `cls._var` refers to `A`'s `_var`, and similarly for `B`. In `inc_static`, decorated with `@staticmethod` there is no argument, you're explicitly referring to `<class '__main__.Base'>`, a different `_var`.

Note the `'_var': 0` attribute in `Base`'s and `A`'s `__dict__`. `@classmethod` is doing what you'd expect it to do, binding members to classes, in this case `A` and `B`.

```
>>> Base.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '_var': 0, 'inc_class': <classmethod 
object at 0x7f23037a8b38>, 'inc_static': <staticmethod object at 
0x7f23037a8c18>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Base' objects>, 
'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Base' objects>, '__doc__': None})

>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})`
```

After calling `Base.inc_static()`:

```
>>> Base.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '_var': 1, 'inc_class': 
<classmethod object at 0x7f23037a8b38>, 'inc_static': <staticmethod 
object at 0x7f23037a8c18>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Base' 
objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Base' objects>, 
'__doc__': None})

>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
```

After calling `A.inc_class()`:

```
>>> Base.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '_var': 1, 'inc_class': 
<classmethod object at 0x7f23037a8b38>, 'inc_static': <staticmethod 
object at 0x7f23037a8c18>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Base' 
objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Base' objects>, 
'__doc__': None})

>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '_var': 1})
```

---

What's interesting is how `A`'s `_var` is initialised. Note that you do `cls._var += 1` before `cls._var` has been defined. As explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#inplace-operators), `cls._var += 1` is equivalent to `cls._var = cls._var; cls._var += 1`. Because of the [way python does lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529987/5090527) the first read of `cls._var` will fail in `A` and continue to find it in `Base`. At the assignment `_var` is added to `A`'s `__dict__` with the value of `Base._var`, and then all is fine.

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     _var = 10
...     @classmethod
...     def inc_class(cls):
...         cls._var += 1
... 
>>> class A(Base):
...     pass
... 
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
>>> A.inc_class()
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '_var': 11})
```

Comment: what makes me crazy is: if I write  "@classmethod
    def inc_class(cls):
        cls._var_boom += 1" I got an error, so python is NOT creating a new '_var_boom' variable for that class instance, but for '_var' it is!

Comment: @cabbi I'm looking into it, but it seems inherited classes take the base's member if you try to use an undefined member of the same name. Note that `+=` expects an existing variable so it should indeed give an error, except with `_var` it picks it up from `Base`.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#inplace-operators) explains it. `cls._var += 1` is equivalent to `cls._var = cls._var; cls._var += 1`. The read of `cls._var` will find `Base._var` and assign its value to a newly defined `A._var`, then the `+=` works fine. I can't find the documentation now for how Python does name lookup, but it probably goes up in scope until (if) it finds it, which is why `Base._var` is picked up before `A._var` is defined.

Comment: with your above comment you FULLY explained me the "magic" python is doing with those variables

Comment: Your last comment should definitely be part of your answer

Comment: @cabbi Glad to be of help. Updated the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the two classes inherit from the Base class, they are completely different objects. Through the instantiation of `a` and `b`, you have two objects that belong to two separate classes. When you call

```
a.inc_class()
b.inc_class()
```

you increment the `_var` attribute of class A once, and then you do the same for class B. Even though they share the same name, they are different objects. If you had a second instance of class A, say `a2`, and you would call the function again, then both calls would manipulate the same variable. This explains how you get your first two outputs.

The third output refers to the Base class object. Again, even though it is the same name, it is a different object. You increment the 3rd object twice, therefore you get `2` as the answer.